# Show holomorphic function in unit disk $D$ s.t. $|f(z)| < M$, $ \forall z \in D$ and $f(0) = 0$ is s.t. $|f(z)| \leq M|z|$

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

To solve this problem I thought about using the function $g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{z}$ because I know it is also holomorphic, and then to apply on $g(z)$ the Maximum Modulus Principle, which I recall below:

*If $f$ is holomorphic in a domain D and continuous on it, then $|f(0)| \leq \max_{z \in D} |f(z)|$*

I know it can be done this way, but I don't understand how to apply this Principle since $g(0)$ is actually not defined.. any clue?

Comment: Do you know the Schwarz lemma? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma

Comment: Thanks Martin I didn't ! But I feel like like it only applies for M = 1, but what if M < 1 for instance ?

Comment: You apply the Schwarz Lemma to $h(z) = f(z)/M$.

Comment: @Pauline it doesn't matter what $M>0$ is. For example, if you know the result for $M=1$, then for an arbitrary $M>0$, simply consider the rescaled function $\frac{1}{M}f(z)$.

Comment: Ah yeah you're both right, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $g(z):=\begin{cases} \frac{f(z)}{z}&\text{if $z\neq 0$}\\ f'(0) & \text{if $z=0$}\end{cases}$.  Now, note that since $f(0)=0$, we have
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{z\to 0}g(z)=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{f(z)}{z}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z-0}=f'(0)=g(0).
\end{align}
Hence, $g$ is clearly holomorphic on $0<|z|<1$, and it is continuous at $0$. Under this situation, it actually follows that $g$ is also holomorphic at the origin (for example, using Morera's theorem, or by Cauchy's inequalities applied to the Laurent expansion of $g$). Now can you continue?

Comment: I see the continuity of g in 0 thank you, and I think I'll try Morera's theorem to show my property with 2 different methods, thanks !

Comment: I now see the link between your post and Schwarz lemma so thanks again